# Change gradient of background color with respect to UISlider value placed into TableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uislider, linear-gradients

i am new to objective C. I want to Change the gradient of background color of a Lable placed in the Cell 
with respect to the UIslider placed in same cell.
As the slider moves from Left to Right the gradient of the Background color should change.
Can anyone guide me how to do it???

Comment: i have implemented some code that set Alpha of UILabel color in uitable view as per slider value change. but don't know how to apply slider value to make gradient color.

Comment: Hi Jatin, can you provide the Code Snippet???

Answer (score 0):

This code will change alpha of background color of UILabel as per slider value change.

first you need to declare slider in custom Cell. as describe bellowed.

Declare slider in SignUpCustomCell.h cell.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface SignUpCustomCell : UITableViewCell {
    UISlider* slider;
    UILabel *lblLeft;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) UISlider* slider;
@property(nonatomic,retain)     UILabel *lblLeft;
@end
```

alloc memory in SignUpCustomCell.m file.

```
#import "SignUpCustomCell.h"
@synthesize slider,lblLeft;
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
if ((self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])) {

 slider=[[UISlider alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 5, 100, 25)];
    [slider setValue:0.0];
    slider.minimumValue=0;
    slider.maximumValue=1;
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.slider];

     self.lblLeft = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    self.lblLeft.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12];
    self.lblLeft.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:135.0/255.0 green:135.0/255.0 blue:135.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    self.lblLeft.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.lblLeft setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.lblLeft];
    [self.lblLeft release];



}
return self;
}
```

After creating custom cell.You will used it where you want.

To used custome cell in SignupViewController.m . we need following steps.

```
#import "SignUpCustomCell.h"
```

Then write code in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

SignUpCustomCell *cell = (SignUpCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[SignUpCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

}
cell.lblLeft.text=@"test app";
cell.slider.tag=indexPath.row;
[cell.slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliedervalue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
return cell;
}

-(void)sliedervalue:(id)sender
{
UISlider* sl=(UISlider*)sender;

NSLog(@"sl=%d",sl.tag);
NSLog(@"sl_value=%f",sl.value);

NSIndexPath *indexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sl.tag inSection:0] ;
SignUpCustomCell *cell = (SignUpCustomCell*)[tblSignup cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.lblLeft.alpha= sl.value;

}
```

Let me know if you have any query.